# Altair not rendering chart in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, vega-lite, altair

I want to view charts in Jupyter notebook using [altair](https://altair-viz.github.io/index.html). So I tried the [tutorial examples](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair_notebooks/tree/master/notebooks). I have installed the required packages. 
This is the code I have:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

# Uncomment/run this line to enable Altair in the classic notebook
#   (this is not necessary in JupyterLab)
alt.renderers.enable('notebook')

cars = data.cars()

chart = alt.Chart(cars).mark_circle().encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    color='Origin',
)

chart
```

I am getting a dictionary instead of a chart. Like so:

```
Chart({
  data:      Acceleration  Cylinders  Displacement  Horsepower  Miles_per_Gallon  \
  0            12.0          8         307.0       130.0              18.0   
  1            11.5          8         350.0       165.0              15.0   
  2            11.0          8         318.0       150.0              18.0   
  3            12.0          8         304.0       150.0              16.0
```

While installing the data sets using this command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge altair vega_datasets notebook vega3
```

I encountered an error:
[image]

Could this error be the reason or is there some other problem?

I am using Jupyter lab. With Ipython version > 5. But I am still only getting textual output.
[image]

Comment: Did you follow the troubleshooting steps here? https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/troubleshooting.html#notebook-textual-chart-representation

Answer (score 0):

When you see a textual output like you saw above within the Jupyter notebook, it means that you are using an IPython kernel that does not yet support mimetype-based rendering of outputs.

To fix this, you need to update IPython to the most recent version. To check the version of IPython, in the notebook run

```
import IPython
IPython.__version__
# 6.2.1
```

You should preferably be using IPython version 5 or later.

Rendering of dynamic outputs like Altair plots is much cleaner in JuptyerLab: I'd recommend switching to using it instead if possible.

Comment: Hi Jake. Loved the video on youtube. I am using Jupyterlab with Ipython version>5. Have added a screenshot in the question section.

Comment: Try upgrading to IPython version 6... I'm not certain exactly when mimetype rendering was added, but the behavior you're seeing is due to having an old ipython version. You might also be running into the same problem as this person: https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/809